# Spring cloud sleuth ExtraFieldPropagation fail in Spring cloud Gateway Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-gateway, distributed-tracing

We are having three modules `Gateway` using `spring-cloud-gateway`, `Service1` and `Service2`.
Gateway call `service1` and `service1` calls `service2`. `Service1` and `Service2` are using spring web flux
Gateway have 3 filters. global filter, Pre filter and post filter.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - name: GlobalFilter
      routes:
        id: service1
        uri: http://localhost:9091/
        predicates:
          - Path=/service1/**
        filters:
          - name: PreFilter
          - name: PostFilter
```

In global filter we are reading value from request body setting set as new baggage key.

```java
ExtraFieldPropagation.set(tracer.currentSpan().context() ,X-CUST_TRAN_ID, transactionID);
```

We have also set Slueth properties like below so that it will be printed in logs as well as forwarded to next services (`service1` and `service2`)

```yaml
    sleuth: 
      baggage-keys: 
        - X-CUST_TRAN_ID
      log:
        slf4j:
          whitelisted-mdc-keys:
           - X-CUST_TRAN_ID
```

Problem we are facing is

`X-CUST_TRAN_ID` values gets send via request and response and printed in `service1` and `service2`'s logs but not in `Gateway` itself.

It does not gets printed either in `GlobalFilter`'s log or in `PreFilter` log statements but gets printed in `PostFilters` log statements. Since `CUST_TRAN_ID` is set in `GlobalFilter`'s filter it should get printed in log statements after set to context.

Please help is there in better way to set the field for propagation as well as printing in log statements.

Answer (score 0):

Sleuth initializes it's context using it's own filter which have a default order. you can try to give an highest precedence of the sleuth filter using the property:

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    web:
      filter-order: -2147483648
```